# Updating early impact product cart version from "3.11 a" to 4.5

Tags: product, cart

I am working on a a website that uses Early Impact Product Cart version 3.11a. Now I need to update the version to the latest version that is 4.5.

Can anyone suggest me the steps to update the product cart version.

Awaiting your replies.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to update to ProductCart version v4.5, you will need to make sure you are enrolled in the [ProductCart Support & Updates Plan](https://www.earlyimpact.com/eistore/productcart/pc/ProductCart-Technical-Support-Updates-Plan-124p463.htm). Once you are enrolled, you will begin by using the "Check for Updates" link under the Help Menu in your ProductCart Control Panel to download the "next" version of ProductCart. After applying the update, you should repeat the process until you receive a message indicating that there are no more available updates (i.e. - you are at the latest version).

For more information on the update and upgrade process, please refer to the following [WIKI articles](http://wiki.earlyimpact.com/?do=search&id=updates&fulltext=Search).

Comment: Thx a lot Cedric Adams and Zsolt Botykai for ur reply. I still have one question in my mind. That is when I update the version of the Product Cart then what changes are needed to be made in the code of my website. The website is made in pure ASP and I am unknown to the way ASP coding is done. Please guide.